# incompatible types using LeftParen

Tags: java

Trying to go through a stack and identify LeftParen and RightParen, but getting error incompatible types token cannot be converted to leftparen?

```
public Double evaluate() {
    Stack<Operator> operatorStack = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Operand> operandStack = new Stack<>();
    while (!getTokenQueue().isEmpty()){
        Token token = getTokenQueue().dequeue();
        if (token instanceof Operand) {
            operandStack.push((Operand)token);
        } else if (token instanceof LeftParen) {
            operatorStack.push((LeftParen)token);
        } else if (token instanceof RightParen) {
            while (!(operatorStack.peek() instanceof LeftParen)) {
                topEval(operatorStack, operandStack);
            }
            operatorStack.pop();  
        } else {
            Operator operator = (Operator)token;
            while (keepEvaluating(operatorStack, operator)) {
                topEval (operatorStack, operandStack);
            }
            operatorStack.push(operator);
        }
    }
    while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
        topEval(operatorStack, operandStack);
    }
    return operandStack.pop().getValue();

}
```

Comment: How is `LeftParen` defined? What is it's relation to `Token`?

Comment: Not sure how to answer your question, so here is the code for LeftParen  public class LeftParen extends Parenthesis {

    public LeftParen() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns the normal precedence level of LeftParen which is highest at 5.
     */
    @Override
    public int precedence() {
        return 5;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the precedence level of LeftParen when on it is on the operator
     * stack, it is lowest at 0.
     */
Override
    public int stackPrecedence() {
        return 0;
    }

}

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and put the definition of `leftParen` in there somewhere? The thing we are interested in, is what `leftParen` extends, in this case: `Parenthesis`. Does `Parenthesis` extend some other class as well, and does this continue until you finally reach `Token`? If not, than you cannot cast a `Token` into a `LeftParen`.